# Assign an existing method by its name from one Unit to a generic TMethod in another unit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Basically, I have an application which will retrieve information out of an INI file and part of this process includes extracting the names -stored in the INI- of some procedures declared at global scope inside another unit.

I use the following to get the SQL method:

```
MyIni.ReadString('SQL', SubStr + '_Insert, '');
```

SubStr is the type of data I want, for example "titles", this is prefixed with the type of SQL procedure I want, in this case "_Insert" therefore, my request here could be seen as:

```
MyIni.ReadString('SQL', 'titles_Insert', '');
```

This would then retrieve the appropriate SQL **procedure name** "InsertTitlesSql" which is displayed inside the INI thus:

```
[SQL]    
titles_Insert=InsertTitlesSql
```

I have a unit which lists the SQL procedures we use.
Like so:

```
unit uSqlLibrary;

interface
  function InsertTitlesSql: string;

implementation

function InsertTitlesSql: string;
begin
  {
    INSERT INTO TITLES (ENGLISH, AFRIKAANS, KEY)
    VALUES (:english,
            :afrikaans,
            :key)
  }
  Result := ''
    +'INSERT INTO TITLES (ENGLISH, AFRIKAANS, KEY) '
    +'VALUES (:english, '
    +'        :afrikaans, '
    +'        :key) ';
end;

end.
```

I've tried TGenericContainer without any success, I've also tried MethodAddress but I don't know how to tell MethodAddress to look at the other unit without an Object to reference (Form1.MethodAddress() for example) my best result so far is this:

```
type
   TExec = procedure of object;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  M : TMethod ;
  E : TExec ;
begin
  M.Code := @Test; // Where "Test" is a procedure inside a secondary Unit. 
  E := TExec(M);
  E;
end;
```

What I'm trying to do is get the SQL procedure by name that I want ( function **InsertTitlesSql** : string;) and assign it to a generic method that behaves in the same way.

My team lead has said that he doesn't want to edit the uSqlLibrary; so I can't do it that way and have thought to go by the method's name instead. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Hope this is clear. Sorry if it's not ( my use of terminology is not so good xD ). I'll try to elaborate on your queries to the best of my knowledge if I can.

Comment: Which version of Delphi. You are going to want new style RTTI. And you will also have to address the fact that `InsertTitlesSql` is not a method of an object. It is a simple procedure declared at global scope.

Comment: XE4. Added it to the top now for reference by others.

Comment: By the way, you are not losing edits. Multiple people are editing your post. It's not just you. This is a wiki here. I trimmed off unnecessary stuff. Please don't keep adding it back!  ;-)

Comment: Oh, haha, sorry. Noted for future reference. :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use RTTI to enumerate procedures with global scope. You can enumerate methods, so you could convert your global procedures to be static class methods.

However, you also state that your team lead does not want you to change `uSqlLibrary`. This seems a little short sighted in my opinion. Feel free to tell him/her that I said so.

Anyway, if you cannot change `uSqlLibrary` then you cannot use RTTI. So you'll need to construct your own lookup table. Use a generic dictionary:

```
uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

var
  ProcTable: TDictionary<string, TProc>;
```

Instantiate it in the usual way. Add your functions at program startup:

```
....
ProcTable.Add('InsertTitlesSql', InsertTitlesSql);
....
```

When you need to look one up and call it do this:

```
var
  Proc: TProc;
....
if not ProcTable.TryGetValue(ProcName, Proc) then
  raise EProcNotFound.CreateFmt(...);
Proc();
```

The default equality comparer used for the key is case-sensitive by default. So you may elect to supply a custom equality comparer that compares keys without case sensitivity.

Comment: Ah! Genius! Thank you so much. :) - Vote Up requires 15 reputation :( - Here's my e-up vote in the mean time, :)

Comment: In due course, you can accept the best answer. Somebody might come along with a better answer. Give it a little while before you accept one.